# OnSoundFinished triggers before Sound actually finished

Tags: c++, audio, unreal-engine4

I can't quite understand it so I'm asking here. I'm spawning AudioComponent with function posted below. It has attached 10 second SoundCue. Then i pause it after 2 seconds and set delay for 30 seconds. Then I want to unpause my sound. The problem is, my dispatcher triggers before it and my sound even cannot be unpaused. Does it get destroyed? Is there any way to prevent it??

```
UAudioComponent* MyAudioClass::LatentSound2D(UObject* WorldContextObject, struct FLatentActionInfo LatentInfo, class USoundBase* Sound, float VolumeMultiplier, float PitchMultiplier, float StartTime, class USoundConcurrency* ConcurrencySettings, bool bPersistAcrossLevelTransition)
{

    MyAudioClassObject= NewObject<MyAudioClass>();//handle needed to bind delegate
    UAudioComponent* AudioComponent = UGameplayStatics::CreateSound2D(WorldContextObject, Sound, VolumeMultiplier, PitchMultiplier, StartTime);//Create AudioComponent
    MyAudioClassObject->BindDelegate(AudioComponent);//Bind delegate to AudioComponent
    AudioComponent->bAutoDestroy = false;
    AudioComponent->bAllowAnyoneToDestroyMe = false;
    AudioComponent->AddToRoot();
    AudioLatentBind(WorldContextObject, LatentInfo, AudioComponent);    //add latent action for this audio component (wait till it ends)
    return AudioComponent;
}
```

Delegate I bind is OnAudioFinished. If there is anything unclear, just let me know. I really need help with it :( This is how it looks like in blueprint

[image]

Comment: You could *at least* tell us what library you are using that provides these classes... We are not mind readers.

Comment: I've just checked this, and it seems that my AudioComponent get's stopped, that's why OnAUdioFinished is firing.However i don't know how can i prevent this stop() call.

Comment: Sure
`#include"MyProjectCodeFunctionLibrary.h"
#include"GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Object.h"
#include "AudioDevice.h"
#include "ActiveSound.h"
#include "LatentActions.h"
#include"MyAudioClass.generated.h"`
Those are my included files.Sorry for mess i'm pretty new here don't really know yet what informations are valueable for other people

Comment: just listing includes doesn't tell us what library this is. What's its name? Where's the project website and documentation?

Comment: For Functions explanation:
BindDelegate is self explaining. It just binds OnAudioFinished to my AudioComponent.

AudioLatentBind is adding new latent acton, which is simply waiting to get signal that audio has finished and then it allows to go on with exec pin.

Comment: I don't really know what are you asking about. This is my private project and there is no website nor documentation. Only "libraries" you poin I'm aware of are those includes in files and other Unreal Engine ones connected.

Comment: In that case, can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/18wEpxYJ

I think i included here every function involved in this process.

Answer (score 0):

I thought CreateSound2D is for UI sounds, and as such is a "fire and forget" action. Since you are creating an AudioComponent, can't you set the sound directly and play the AudioComponent instead of using CreateSound2D?